# Duplicate values keep removing for other product pages

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not sure how to type the title so I will explain it here. Firstly, this is my database. (i replaced 'product' as 'p' to save space in database here.

```
p_id|p_name|p_image      | p_category  | p_col | p_size
1   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Coral | 64GB
2   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Coral | 128GB
3   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Coral | 256GB
4   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Blue  | 64GB
5   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Blue  | 128GB
6   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Blue  | 256GB
7   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Black | 64GB
8   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Black | 128GB
9   | Xs   |xsmax.png    | Smartphones | Black | 256GB
10  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Silver| 64GB
11  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Silver| 128GB
12  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Silver| 256GB
13  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Black | 64GB
14  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Black | 128GB
15  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Black | 256GB
16  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Gold  | 64GB
17  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Gold  | 128GB
18  | Xr   |xrmax.png    | Smartphones | Gold  | 256GB


<?php
    include("dataconnection.php");

    if(isset($_GET['view'])) 
        {
            $name = $_GET["proid"]; //name of the product (example:Xr)
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = '$name' ");
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);         
        }
?>



    <?php $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (product_id, product_col) in ( SELECT MIN(product_id), product_col FROM products GROUP BY product_col  ) AND product_name='$name' "); ?>


          <div class="product-color">
            <span>Color</span>
            <div class="color-choose">
              <div>
                <?php while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))  { 
              echo $row1['product_col'];
            ?>              
                <?php           
                }
?>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
```

I wanted to display the colors available for each product, without showing the duplicates. I thought I managed to do it by using the query above, but the query carries for the second product as well. It shows like this.

When I Click Xs (1st product)

```
Color I need = Coral, Blue, Black
Color shown = Coral, Blue, Black
```

When I Click Xr (1st product)

```
Color I need = Silver, Black, Gold
Color shown = Silver,Gold
```

The query applies to all products, thus removing all duplicates, I want it to remove duplicate color just from the name, which is gotten from proid.

UPDATE:SOLVED BY jameson2012

Comment: I'm not sure you need the where in sub query, can't you just ````select distinct(product_name) ...```` ? and then do ````select distinct(product_name) group by product_col````  or maybe ````select distinct(product_col)  from table where product_name = :product_name```` for the colors?  Also you need to use prepared statements as this code is easily injectable https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Oh of course, I feel so dumb now ,thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is redundant. All you need is the second query (minus that nonsensical bit at the end). Incidentally, I suspect that your second query is less efficient than one of the more normal forms, e.g.:

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant
  FROM products x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(product_id) product_id
            , product_name 
         FROM products 
       WHERE product_name = :name -- optional line
        GROUP 
           BY product_name  ) x
    ON y.product_name = x.product_name
   AND y.product_id = x.product_id
```

Also see about the importance of prepared and bound queries